# Get value of custom atrribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, get, attributes

I have this code

```
var elem = document.getElementById('EMM');
```

```
<span id="EMM" data-var="MM"></span>
```

Problem is I want to access the value of `data-var` attribute in `elem` in JavaScript, something like `elem.attributevalue('data-var')`

Comment: `.getAttribute('data-var')`

Answer (score 1):

Use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('EMM');
alert(elem.getAttribute('data-var'));
```

```html
<span id="EMM" data-var="MM"></span>
```

Comment: And how can I identify weather `elem` has `data-var` attribute or not like in `<span id="EMM"></span>` the `span` don't have a `data-var` attribute

Comment: @EMM, getAttribute will return null if the attribute does not exist. So just check if it equals null

Comment: @EMM If you do not have an attribute elem.getAttribute() would return a null value

Comment: @EMM, if you found an answer helpful, you should 'accept' it by clicking the green checkbox near the voting arrows of the answer

Comment: `elem.dataset` as well